# Mac OSX keeps mixing up my monitors. Any way to distinguish them?

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors

I have two Mobile Pixel Trio Max monitors connected to my MacBook Pro (newest model) via usb-c cables. One is on the left and horizontal and on is on the right and vertical. So I had to take a couple steps to rotate the right monitor and then move the monitors around in the display settings so the mouse moved between them correctly.

This all worked fine, but the problem is that every time my computer goes to sleep there seems to be a 50% chance or so that the OS will mix up the two monitors. When the computer wakes up, the rotation is applied to the left monitor and they also switched places so the mouse moves between them incorrectly. It only takes a minute to fix, but its very annoying to have to do this constantly.

By the way, I never touch the cables. They are always plugged in the same way.

Basically, it seems like the OS can't distinguish the two monitors (even though these monitors are designed to be used in pairs like this and this Mac is designed to be used with multiple monitors). Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Sometimes the only fix is to let it win. Figure out which it prefers and set them up that way.

Comment: Tried it and doesn't work :( It seems to be completely random

Comment: Then you may have to resort to waking them manually before you wake the computer.

Comment: Don't think that is possible? The trio max displays have no buttons or controls of any kind so they only wake when the computer wakes

Comment: I don't know of a third way, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is extremely aggravating, so I understand your frustration.

One method that somehow always works for me is to toggle through each display as my "main" display, and it somehow brings my windows back to where they were before.

For example, say you have three monitors (two external, and your laptop/desktop screen). One of them stays the same, eg the main display, and the other two get swapped:

[Two monitors' windows swapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCRyE.png)

Follow these **steps**:

- Right-click on one of your non-main displays, set it to be your main display
- Right-click on the next remaining display that was not originally your main display, set it to be your main display
- Right-click on your original main display, and set it to your main display

Visualization:

[set each display to main display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whppS.png)

**Result**: Your windows should be displayed on the correct monitor

Notes:

- if you are on an earlier version of OSX and you have the white "command bar" to identify your main display, you can drag that to each screen in a circle, just as you would right-click and select main display
- if you have two monitors that swap, this should still work; at least it did in the past for me